# How do i convert a string list with numbers with commas to an integer list in python

Tags: python, string, list, type-conversion, integer

How do i convert this to a list of integer in python?

my code:

```
lst = input("Kindly input a string")

[int(element) for element in lst]
```

I keep getting

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '['

Comment: Looks like the input contains '[' which cannot be converted to an integer. Please give an example of the intended input and expected output

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are entering string inputs like:

```
"[1, 2, 3]"
```

you may use `ast.literal_eval`:

```py
import ast
inp = "[1, 2, 3]"
lst = ast.literal_eval(inp)
print(lst)  # [1, 2, 3]
```

Or, you could use `re.findall`:

```py
inp = "[1, 2, 3]"
lst = [int(x) for x in re.findall(r'\d+', inp)]
print(lst)  # [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use python eval:

```
eval("[1, 2, 3]")
# [1, 2, 3]

eval("2,4,2 ,2 ,23, 23")
# (2, 4, 2, 2, 23, 23)
```

exact case would be:

```
lst = eval(input("Kindly input a string"))
```

Answer (score 0):

By string manipulations: remove the square brackets with `str.strip`, make a list of numbers by splitting the string at each occurrence of `', '` (here for simplicity it is assumed there is *always* a white space after the `,`) and finally cast each string-number to integer.

```
s = "[1, 2, 3]"

l = list(map(int, s.strip('][').split(', ')))
print(l)
```

More complex situation,for example when the presence of the white space is not sure it can be solved with a `for`-loop approach or with regular expression. For nested list then `ast.literal_eval` is *the* choice.